# Modify tracker to work with ga.js and analytics.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am modifying an existing document and outbound link tracker for ga.js to also work with analytics.js so it can be added to our old and new sites.

I have added 2 IF statements but am unsure if I have converted it correctly (especially the href and 'b._trackEvent' arguments). Here is my attempt:

```
function docLinkTracking(thing){
    href = $(thing).attr('href');
    if (href) {
        var href_lower = href.toLowerCase();
        var filetypes = /\.(zip|exe|pdf|doc.?|xls.?|ppt.?|mp3|mp4|flv|txt|csv|vsd)$/i;
        var file_extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : 'undefined';
        file_extension = file_extension.toString();

        //track documents links
        if (href.match(filetypes)) {
            //my guesses..
            if (typeof ga !== 'undefined') {
                ga('send', 'event', 'Downloads', file_extension, {'nonInteraction': href});
                ga('send', 'b.event', 'Downloads', file_extension, {'nonInteraction': href});
            }
            //original
            if (typeof _gaq !== 'undefined') {
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', file_extension, href]);
                _gaq.push(['b._trackEvent', 'Downloads', file_extension, href]);
            }
        }

        //track outbound links
        if (href_lower.substr(0, 4) == "http") {
            var domain = document.domain.replace("www.", '');
            if (href_lower.indexOf(domain) == -1) {
                href = href.replace("http://", '');
                href = href.replace("https://", '');
                //my guesses..
                if (typeof ga !== 'undefined') {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'Outbound Traffic', {'nonInteraction': href});
                    ga('send', 'b.event', 'Outbound Traffic', {'nonInteraction': href});
                }
                //original
                if (typeof _gaq !== 'undefined') {                    
                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Outbound Traffic', href]);
                    _gaq.push(['b._trackEvent', 'Outbound Traffic', href]);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me correct both '//my guesses..' blocks as I need to pass this code on to be implemented.